# iOS device battery life when developing

Tags: ios, battery, lightning

I have an iPhone and an iPad that are constantly connected through USB to my MacBook Pro 8 hours a day.

The battery of both device is always at 100%. Will this hurt my devices battery life?

I've researched into alternatives to build and debug from XCode via WIFI or Bluetooth but I find out that those features were dropped by Apple due to stability issues.

Are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will hurt your iPhone. The charger is smart enough to stop charging when necessary. It is the number of charge/use cycles that degrade battery life and if you are attached most of the time its doing neither.

I have had mine attached to a cable most of the time for over a year and not seen any degradation.

Comment: Nice to know! Does the same apply to a MacBook Pro? Can I keep it connected without seeing any degradations?

Comment: macbook should be same.

Answer (score 0):

But it will affect your battey during long run. I suggest to use your phone as you reach home and let it discharge till 40 %. And then charge again. This will manager maintain battery cycles and its health will be fine this way.